# Support in netty for datagram packets over unix domain sockets?

Tags: sockets, unix, netty

I've just started looking at netty for some projects and have been able to get some simple client and server examples running that use INET and unix domain sockets to send messages back and forth.  I've also been able to send datagram packets over INET sockets.  But I have a need to send datagram packets over UNIX domain sockets.  Is this supported in netty?  If so, could someone point me at documentation or an example?  I suspect this is not supported given that the DatagramPacket explicitly takes InetSocketAddress.  If not supported, would it be feasible to add this to netty?

Answer (score -1):

> Is this supported in netty?

Yes. Below is a simple example I wrote.

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.*;
import io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollDomainSocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollServerDomainSocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.unix.DomainSocketAddress;

/**
 * @author louyl
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String sockPath = "/tmp/echo.sock";
        final ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        EventLoopGroup serverBossEventLoopGroup = new EpollEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup serverWorkerEventLoopGroup = new EpollEventLoopGroup();
        bootstrap.group(serverBossEventLoopGroup, serverWorkerEventLoopGroup)
            .localAddress(new DomainSocketAddress(sockPath))
            .channel(EpollServerDomainSocketChannel.class)
            .childHandler(
                new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(final Channel channel) throws Exception {
                        channel.pipeline().addLast(
                            new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                                    final ByteBuf buff = ctx.alloc().buffer();
                                    buff.writeBytes("This is a test".getBytes());
                                    ctx.writeAndFlush(buff).addListeners(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                                                future.channel().close();
                                                future.channel().parent().close();
                                            }
                                        });
                                }
                            }
                                                   );
                    }
                }
                          );
        final ChannelFuture serverFuture = bootstrap.bind().sync();

        final Bootstrap bootstrapClient = new Bootstrap();
        EventLoopGroup clientEventLoop = new EpollEventLoopGroup();
        bootstrapClient.group(clientEventLoop)
            .channel(EpollDomainSocketChannel.class)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(final Channel channel) throws Exception {
                        channel.pipeline().addLast(
                            new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final Object msg) throws Exception {
                                    final ByteBuf buff = (ByteBuf) msg;
                                    try {
                                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buff.readableBytes()];
                                        buff.getBytes(0, bytes);
                                        System.out.println(new String(bytes));
                                    } finally {
                                        buff.release();
                                    }
                                    ctx.close();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void exceptionCaught(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final Throwable cause) throws Exception {
                                    System.out.println("Error occur when reading from Unix domain socket: " + cause.getMessage());
                                    ctx.close();
                                }
                            }
                                                   );
                    }
                }
                );
        final ChannelFuture clientFuture = bootstrapClient.connect(new DomainSocketAddress(sockPath)).sync();

        clientFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        serverFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        serverBossEventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        serverWorkerEventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        clientEventLoop.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a Datagram Socket, isn't it?